# How can I solve this exception related to resizable UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am getting this exception when I run my code:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:  '-[UIImageView _isResizable]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc6b47301a0'

My code is here:

```
struct data {
    let text : String!
    let pic : UIImage!
}

class ResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cellData = [data]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        cellData = [data(text: "first", pic: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2017-06-28 at 1.55.48 PM")),
                data(text: "second", pic: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2017-06-28 at 1.55.48 PM")),
                data(text: "third", pic: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2017-06-28 at 1.55.48 PM"))]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed( "resultsVOiew", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ResultsViewCell

        cell.imageView1.image = cellData[indexPath.row].pic
        cell.OrganizationName.text = cellData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 91
    }

}
```

Please help! I have looked at other stackOverflow posts but couldn't write find where I am stuck. I have looked into the differences in UIImageView and UIImage but can't see where the disconnect is.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error? What version of iOS? What version of Xcode?

Comment: I cleaned up your code a bit to help me look at things. Nothing jumps out, except that the error is related to a `UIImageView` and you have exactly one line of code addressing one. (Nothing concerning a `UIImage` is included, so I'm not sure what you are saying there.) Have you set a breakpoint? Are you sure that the `cellData` array is properly populated? Have you tried breaking things down a bit - in particular, `pic: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2017-06-28 at 1.55.48 PM")` is a huge way of having runtime errors crop up. Maybe make sure each *component* is good?